# How works if() statement

Tags: c++

I have a simple question for optimizing my code.

```
bool myfunc();

if (false && true && myfunc())
{
}
```

Will the function `myfunc()` be called ??

Comment: In short: No, it won't be called.

Comment: No. The if condition will stop at the first false and not test the other two conditions.

Comment: Guys. Answers go in the _ANSWER SECTION_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

`&&` and `||` have short-circuit evaluation, that is, once the result is definitely known (`false` for `&&` and `true` for `||`) evaluation stops. And it's always strictly left-to-right.

In this case the compiler might even choose to elide the `if` statement completely, since the condition at compile-time is known to be `false` and thus the code afterwards is unreachable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help

Comment: To be precise, only the built-in logical expressions have short-circuiting semantics. When the operators are overloaded, the expression is a normal function call.

Answer (score 8):

Because C++ have [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of conditions, no the function will not be called since the first`false` makes the whole expression false anyway.

If you change the order, so you put the function call first (i.e. `myfunc() && false && true`) then the function will be called. The result of the expression will still be `false` though, no matter what `myfunc` returns.

Comment: In case you write the order as in your answer, doesn't the compiler then optimize out the whole if statement and everything in its scope? Or does it call the function in case there is an exception in there?

Comment: @Chiel If the function is an external function from another translation unit, then the compiler can't know what it does, or what side-effects it have, so the function call can't be optimized away. What it can optimize is that it doesn't do anything else but the call, and disregard the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

No, `myfunc()` will not be called, because of the first `false`, compiler will stop there. It's called short circuit evaluation.